# How should I connect a new outlet cable to a box with two existing cables?

Tags: receptacle

I have a outlet that supplies a garage door opener. It has two black wires and two white wires. One black is hot. I want to use this outlet as a power source to install outdoor spotlight. I ran new wire to outlet but not sure how to connect wires.

Also when I unplug opener and plug it into another working outlet opener would not come on. It only will work on outlet I want to use as a power source.

Comment: I take it this outlet is always hot? (i.e. no switches that turn it on and off)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood’s answer , what concerns me is the opener only works on that outlet, is the other outlet switched or a bad extension cord? With strange stuff happening I would want to check it out and make sure someone did not learn the trade in Disneyland (mickey mouse) something.

Comment: That part didn't make much sense to me. I suspect a switched or otherwise disabled outlet was used for that test.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that one cable is the incoming power and one goes out to more outlets or lights, just keep everything connected by color--blacks together and whites together.

I'm a little concerned that you're doing electrical work without the skills to trace a simple circuit, though. Please be sure that you have an understanding of proper connection techniques, wire size requirements, and other best practices. A little reading of a house wiring guide would be wise. You don't want to burn your house down.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to open the circuit breaker and test the outlet BEFORE attempting to change anything. Just sayin'